# How to resize a picture?

Tags: image, delphi, resize, delphi-7

I have image (500x500) but I need to resize it to 200x200 and paint it on TImage. How to achieve such result?

**Note**
I know about `Stretch` property in TImage, but I want to resize the image programmatically.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you know that the new dimensions are not greater than the original ones, you can simply do

```
procedure ShrinkBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; const NewWidth, NewHeight: integer);
begin
  Bitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw(
    Rect(0, 0, NewWidth, NewHeight),
    Bitmap);
  Bitmap.SetSize(NewWidth, NewHeight);
end;
```

I leave it as an exercise to write the corresponding code if you know that the new dimensions are not *smaller* than the original ones.

If you want a general function, you could do

```
procedure ResizeBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; const NewWidth, NewHeight: integer);
var
  buffer: TBitmap;
begin
  buffer := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    buffer.SetSize(NewWidth, NewHeight);
    buffer.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, NewWidth, NewHeight), Bitmap);
    Bitmap.SetSize(NewWidth, NewHeight);
    Bitmap.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, buffer);
  finally
    buffer.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This approach has the downside of doing *two* pixel-copy operations. I can think of at least two solutions to that problem. (Which?)

Comment: @Robers: Personally, I always work with bitmaps when I need to manipulate them.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand That works only when you resize it to a small dem, if you have a bmp file with 48x48 and want to resize it to 256x256, this procedure will fail.

Comment: @Sami: Very true. My bad.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I have a Problem with your Code, it works but i have tried it with a Picture which I have taken with my phone and that picutes gets rotated and a part of it gets cut off can you tell me why this has happend? I am using the first part of you answer and it has also worked with all other Pictures but the Picture from the phone doesn't work. Please help

Comment: The image quality obtained with StretchDraw is quite poor. But at least the function is fast.

Comment: @ServerOverflow: Yes, and that's perhaps not very surprising considering that the GDI (the graphics API this is based on) is very old, from the early 90s. Today, you can use Direct2D if you want better quality.

Comment: True. My comment was only for other to know the disadvantages of the function :)

Answer (score 14):

Great usability and picture quality offers the `ResizeImage` function(s) from the unit <sup>1)</sup> below. The code depends on [Graphics32](http://graphics32.org/wiki/), [GIFImage](http://melander.dk/delphi/gifimage/) <sup>2)</sup> and [PNGImage](http://pngimage.codeplex.com/) <sup>2)</sup>.

The function takes two file names or two streams. Input is (automatically detected as) BMP, PNG, GIF or JPG, output is always JPG.

```
unit AwResizeImage;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Math, JPEG, GR32, GIFImage, PNGImage,
  GR32_Resamplers;

type
  TImageType = (itUnknown, itBMP, itGIF, itJPG, itPNG);
  TImageInfo = record
    ImgType: TImageType;
    Width: Cardinal;
    Height: Cardinal;
  end;

  function GetImageInfo(const AFilename: String): TImageInfo; overload;
  function GetImageInfo(const AStream: TStream): TImageInfo; overload;

  function ResizeImage(const ASource, ADest: String; const AWidth,
    AHeight: Integer; const ABackColor: TColor;
    const AType: TImageType = itUnknown): Boolean; overload;
  function ResizeImage(const ASource, ADest: TStream; const AWidth,
    AHeight: Integer; const ABackColor: TColor;
    const AType: TImageType = itUnknown): Boolean; overload;

implementation

type
  TGetDimensions = procedure(const ASource: TStream;
    var AImageInfo: TImageInfo);

  TCardinal = record
    case Byte of
      0: (Value: Cardinal);
      1: (Byte1, Byte2, Byte3, Byte4: Byte);
  end;

  TWord = record
    case Byte of
      0: (Value: Word);
      1: (Byte1, Byte2: Byte);
  end;

  TPNGIHDRChunk = packed record
    Width: Cardinal;
    Height: Cardinal;
    Bitdepth: Byte;
    Colortype: Byte;
    Compression: Byte;
    Filter: Byte;
    Interlace: Byte;
  end;

  TGIFHeader = packed record
    Signature: array[0..2] of Char;
    Version: array[0..2] of Char;
    Width: Word;
    Height: Word;
  end;

  TJPGChunk = record
    ID: Word;
    Length: Word;
  end;

  TJPGHeader = packed record
    Reserved: Byte;
    Height: Word;
    Width: Word;
  end;

const
  SIG_BMP: array[0..1] of Char = ('B', 'M');
  SIG_GIF: array[0..2] of Char = ('G', 'I', 'F');
  SIG_JPG: array[0..2] of Char = (#255, #216, #255);
  SIG_PNG: array[0..7] of Char = (#137, #80, #78, #71, #13, #10, #26, #10);

function SwapBytes(const ASource: Cardinal): Cardinal; overload;
var
  mwSource: TCardinal;
  mwDest: TCardinal;
begin
  mwSource.Value := ASource;
  mwDest.Byte1 := mwSource.Byte4;
  mwDest.Byte2 := mwSource.Byte3;
  mwDest.Byte3 := mwSource.Byte2;
  mwDest.Byte4 := mwSource.Byte1;
  Result := mwDest.Value;
end;

function SwapBytes(const ASource: Word): Word; overload;
var
  mwSource: TWord;
  mwDest: TWord;
begin
  mwSource.Value  := ASource;
  mwDest.Byte1 := mwSource.Byte2;
  mwDest.Byte2 := mwSource.Byte1;
  Result := mwDest.Value;
end;

procedure GetBMPDimensions(const ASource: TStream; var AImageInfo: TImageInfo);
var
  bmpFileHeader: TBitmapFileHeader;
  bmpInfoHeader: TBitmapInfoHeader;
begin
  FillChar(bmpFileHeader, SizeOf(TBitmapFileHeader), #0);
  FillChar(bmpInfoHeader, SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader), #0);
  ASource.Read(bmpFileHeader, SizeOf(TBitmapFileHeader));
  ASource.Read(bmpInfoHeader, SizeOf(TBitmapInfoHeader));
  AImageInfo.Width := bmpInfoHeader.biWidth;
  AImageInfo.Height := bmpInfoHeader.biHeight;
end;

procedure GetGIFDimensions(const ASource: TStream; var AImageInfo: TImageInfo);
var
  gifHeader: TGIFHeader;
begin
  FillChar(gifHeader, SizeOf(TGIFHeader), #0);
  ASource.Read(gifHeader, SizeOf(TGIFHeader));
  AImageInfo.Width := gifHeader.Width;
  AImageInfo.Height := gifHeader.Height;
end;

procedure GetJPGDimensions(const ASource: TStream; var AImageInfo: TImageInfo);
var
  cSig: array[0..1] of Char;
  jpgChunk: TJPGChunk;
  jpgHeader: TJPGHeader;
  iSize: Integer;
  iRead: Integer;
begin
  FillChar(cSig, SizeOf(cSig), #0);
  ASource.Read(cSig, SizeOf(cSig));
  iSize := SizeOf(TJPGChunk);
  repeat
    FillChar(jpgChunk, iSize, #0);
    iRead := ASource.Read(jpgChunk, iSize);
    if iRead <> iSize then
      Break;
    if jpgChunk.ID = $C0FF then
    begin
      ASource.Read(jpgHeader, SizeOf(TJPGHeader));
      AImageInfo.Width := SwapBytes(jpgHeader.Width);
      AImageInfo.Height := SwapBytes(jpgHeader.Height);
      Break;
    end
    else
      ASource.Position := ASource.Position + (SwapBytes(jpgChunk.Length) - 2);
  until False;
end;

procedure GetPNGDimensions(const ASource: TStream; var AImageInfo: TImageInfo);
var
  cSig: array[0..7] of Char;
  cChunkLen: Cardinal;
  cChunkType: array[0..3] of Char;
  ihdrData: TPNGIHDRChunk;
begin
  FillChar(cSig, SizeOf(cSig), #0);
  FillChar(cChunkType, SizeOf(cChunkType), #0);
  ASource.Read(cSig, SizeOf(cSig));
  cChunkLen := 0;
  ASource.Read(cChunkLen, SizeOf(Cardinal));
  cChunkLen := SwapBytes(cChunkLen);
  if cChunkLen = SizeOf(TPNGIHDRChunk) then
  begin
    ASource.Read(cChunkType, SizeOf(cChunkType));
    if AnsiUpperCase(cChunkType) = 'IHDR' then
    begin
      FillChar(ihdrData, SizeOf(TPNGIHDRChunk), #0);
      ASource.Read(ihdrData, SizeOf(TPNGIHDRChunk));
      AImageInfo.Width := SwapBytes(ihdrData.Width);
      AImageInfo.Height := SwapBytes(ihdrData.Height);
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetImageInfo(const AFilename: String): TImageInfo;
var
  fsImage: TFileStream;
begin
  fsImage := TFileStream.Create(AFilename, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    Result := GetImageInfo(fsImage);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fsImage);
  end;
end;

function GetImageInfo(const AStream: TStream): TImageInfo;
var
  iPos: Integer;
  cBuffer: array[0..2] of Char;
  cPNGBuffer: array[0..4] of Char;
  GetDimensions: TGetDimensions;
begin
  GetDimensions := nil;
  Result.ImgType := itUnknown;
  Result.Width := 0;
  Result.Height := 0;
  FillChar(cBuffer, SizeOf(cBuffer), #0);
  FillChar(cPNGBuffer, SizeOf(cPNGBuffer), #0);
  iPos := AStream.Position;
  AStream.Read(cBuffer, SizeOf(cBuffer));
  if cBuffer = SIG_GIF then
  begin
    Result.ImgType := itGIF;
    GetDimensions := GetGIFDimensions;
  end
  else if cBuffer = SIG_JPG then
  begin
    Result.ImgType := itJPG;
    GetDimensions := GetJPGDimensions;
  end
  else if cBuffer = Copy(SIG_PNG, 1, 3) then
  begin
    AStream.Read(cPNGBuffer, SizeOf(cPNGBuffer));
    if cPNGBuffer = Copy(SIG_PNG, 4, 5) then
    begin
      Result.ImgType := itPNG;
      GetDimensions := GetPNGDimensions;
    end;
  end
  else if Copy(cBuffer, 1, 2) = SIG_BMP then
  begin
    Result.ImgType := itBMP;
    GetDimensions := GetBMPDimensions;
  end;
  AStream.Position := iPos;
  if Assigned(GetDimensions) then
  begin
    GetDimensions(AStream, Result);
    AStream.Position := iPos;
  end;
end;

procedure GIFToBMP(const ASource: TStream; const ADest: TBitmap);
var
  imgSource: TGIFImage;
begin
  imgSource := TGIFImage.Create();
  try
    imgSource.LoadFromStream(ASource);
    ADest.Assign(imgSource);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(imgSource);
  end;
end;

procedure JPGToBMP(const ASource: TStream; const ADest: TBitmap);
var
  imgSource: TJPEGImage;
begin
  imgSource := TJPEGImage.Create();
  try
    imgSource.LoadFromStream(ASource);
    ADest.Assign(imgSource);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(imgSource);
  end;
end;

procedure PNGToBMP(const ASource: TStream; const ADest: TBitmap);
var
  imgSource: TPNGImage;
begin
  imgSource := TPNGImage.Create();
  try
    imgSource.LoadFromStream(ASource);
    ADest.Assign(imgSource);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(imgSource);
  end;
end;

function ResizeImage(const ASource, ADest: String; const AWidth,
  AHeight: Integer; const ABackColor: TColor;
  const AType: TImageType = itUnknown): Boolean;
var
  fsSource: TFileStream;
  fsDest: TFileStream;
begin
  Result := False;
  fsSource := TFileStream.Create(ASource, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
  try
    fsDest := TFileStream.Create(ADest, fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
    try
      Result := not Result; //hide compiler hint
      Result := ResizeImage(fsSource, fsDest, AWidth, AHeight, ABackColor, AType);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(fsDest);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(fsSource);
  end;
end;

function ResizeImage(const ASource, ADest: TStream; const AWidth,
  AHeight: Integer; const ABackColor: TColor;
  const AType: TImageType = itUnknown): Boolean;
var
  itImage: TImageType;
  ifImage: TImageInfo;
  bmpTemp: TBitmap;
  bmpSource: TBitmap32;
  bmpResized: TBitmap32;
  cBackColor: TColor32;
  rSource: TRect;
  rDest: TRect;
  dWFactor: Double;
  dHFactor: Double;
  dFactor: Double;
  iSrcWidth: Integer;
  iSrcHeight: Integer;
  iWidth: Integer;
  iHeight: Integer;
  jpgTemp: TJPEGImage;
begin
  Result := False;
  itImage := AType;
  if itImage = itUnknown then
  begin
    ifImage := GetImageInfo(ASource);
    itImage := ifImage.ImgType;
    if itImage = itUnknown then
      Exit;
  end;
  bmpTemp := TBitmap.Create();
  try
    case itImage of
      itBMP: bmpTemp.LoadFromStream(ASource);
      itGIF: GIFToBMP(ASource, bmpTemp);
      itJPG: JPGToBMP(ASource, bmpTemp);
      itPNG: PNGToBMP(ASource, bmpTemp);
    end;
    bmpSource := TBitmap32.Create();
    bmpResized := TBitmap32.Create();
    try
      cBackColor  := Color32(ABackColor);
      bmpSource.Assign(bmpTemp);
      bmpResized.Width := AWidth;
      bmpResized.Height := AHeight;
      bmpResized.Clear(cBackColor);
      iSrcWidth := bmpSource.Width;
      iSrcHeight := bmpSource.Height;
      iWidth := iSrcWidth;
      iHeight := iSrcHeight;
      with rSource do
      begin
        Left := 0;
        Top := 0;
        Right := iSrcWidth;
        Bottom := iSrcHeight;
      end;
      if (iWidth > AWidth) or (iHeight > AHeight) then
      begin
        dWFactor := AWidth / iWidth;
        dHFactor := AHeight / iHeight;
        if (dWFactor > dHFactor) then
          dFactor := dHFactor
        else
          dFactor := dWFactor;
        iWidth := Floor(iWidth * dFactor);
        iHeight := Floor(iHeight * dFactor);
      end;
      with rDest do
      begin
        Left := Floor((AWidth - iWidth) / 2);
        Top := Floor((AHeight - iHeight) / 2);
        Right := Left + iWidth;
        Bottom := Top + iHeight;
      end;
      bmpSource.Resampler := TKernelResampler.Create;
      TKernelResampler(bmpSource.Resampler).Kernel := TLanczosKernel.Create;
      bmpSource.DrawMode := dmOpaque;
      bmpResized.Draw(rDest, rSource, bmpSource);
      bmpTemp.Assign(bmpResized);
      jpgTemp := TJPEGImage.Create();
      jpgTemp.CompressionQuality := 80;
      try
        jpgTemp.Assign(bmpTemp);
        jpgTemp.SaveToStream(ADest);
        Result := True;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(jpgTemp);
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(bmpResized);
      FreeAndNil(bmpSource);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(bmpTemp);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Notes:

- <sup>1)</sup> I surely didn't code this myself, but do not know anymore where I got it from.
- <sup>2)</sup> Included in recent Delphi versions.
- If compiling with more recent versions of RAD Studio/Delphi XE, remember to substitute char with ansichar for all char variable types otherwise the GetImageInfo will not work, and it will not resize the image.  This is needed as the default char type is two bytes, and the function expects it to be single byte.

Comment: Graphics32 is a bit overkill IF you ONLY need a resize. JanFX is much more portable.

Answer (score 8):

I've often used the `SmoothResize` procedure from this page: http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/printcode.php?id=1896

The scaling is much better than the StretchDraw function.

Don't let the title fool you. The page demonstrates resizing JPGs, but the SmoothResize procedure itself uses bitmaps for resizing. Resizing PNGs could be done in a similar matter, but you will loose transparency if you use this procedure.

Comment: This code does Bitmaps only. If you use TPNGImage, you can draw the PNG image on a bitmap canvas and resize that, but it will kill any transparency in the image. For true PNG resizing, I think you'll need NGLN's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Please see this simple example on how to resize an image using two TBitmap32 objects. The TBitmap32 is the best in terms of speed/image quality ratio.

It requires the https://github.com/graphics32 library.

```
uses 
  GR32, GR32_Resamplers;

procedure Resize(InputPicture: TBitmap; OutputImage: TImage; const DstWidth, DstHeigth: Integer);
var
  Src, Dst: TBitmap32;
begin
  Dst := nil;
  try
    Src := TBitmap32.Create;
    try
      Src.Assign(InputPicture);
      SetHighQualityStretchFilter(Src);
      Dst := TBitmap32.Create;
      Dst.SetSize(DstWidth, DstHeigth);
      Src.DrawTo(Dst, Rect(0, 0, DstWidth, DstHeigth), Rect(0, 0, Src.Width, Src.Height));
    finally
      FreeAndNil(Src);
    end;
    OutputImage.Assign(Dst);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Dst);
  end;
end;

// If you need to set a highest quality resampler, use this helper routine to configure it
procedure SetHighQualityStretchFilter(B: TBitmap32);
var
  KR: TKernelResampler;
begin
  if not (B.Resampler is TKernelResampler) then
  begin
    KR := TKernelResampler.Create(B);
    KR.Kernel := TLanczosKernel.Create;
  end
  else
  begin
    KR := B.Resampler as TKernelResampler;
    if not (KR.Kernel is TLanczosKernel) then
    begin
      KR.Kernel.Free;
      KR.Kernel := TLanczosKernel.Create;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Graphics32 is a bit overkill IF you ONLY need a resize. JanFX is much more portable.

Comment: @ServerOverflow - you can provide a ready resize code sample for JanFX in addition to the code sample I have provided for Graphics32, otherwise it is a value judgment on what is better.

Comment: Yes. The code is: JanFx.SmoothResize(SrcBMP, DstBMP); It will enlarge Src bitmap to fit Dst bitmap. That's it. Needs 50ms for a 2M pixel image to resize.  Its quality, compared to Hermite is too sharp on resize down and quite good on resize up. Hermite requires 655ms for the same image.

Comment: But I was not talking about quality in my first comment (please do read it again). I just said that if all you need is a resampler, it might be overkill to use the whole Graphics32 lib. JanFx is much smaller and portable.  PS: don't read again between the lines: I am not saying that Gr32 is not good!

Comment: @ServerOverflow thank you for your code sample at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46043963/6910868 (I have already upvoted your answer) :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have done quite some extensive testing (10 algorithms/libraries) in this direction. I only mention the first three.
If you are lazy to read, skip to MY conclusions
:)

---

**JanFX library**
Now incorporated into the fat Jedi distribution. FORTUNATELY you can extract this file from Jedi without having to drag the whole mammoth into your project.
It gives a very nice smoothing (not as good as Graphics32 but good enough) but much, much faster.

Note: The JanFX.pas in Jedi is bugged: does not work when range checking is on. You need to define {$R-} before the code. That's it. The guys at Jedi entered this bug because they ALWAYS compile with range checking off.

```
JanFx.SmoothResize(SrcBMP, DstBMP);
```

---

**Graphics32 lib**
Super good output quality.
But if all you need is a resampler, it might be overkill to use the entire Graphics32 lib. JanFx is much smaller and portable. Graphics32 will give you slightly better results, BUT the processing times are about 10x higher!

---

**StretchBlt**
If you don't want to involve external libraries, look into StretchBlt.
This will not give you the best results as Graphics32, but it is ridiculously faster, compared with Graphics32.
(see code below)

---

**Conclusion:**

StretchBlt is my final choice for my programs, being the best trade between the output quality and speed. It does a good job not only in downsampling but also in upsampling.

```
   {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Uses MS Windows StretchBlt
   BEST (see tester)

   Zoom: In/Out
   Keep aspect ration: No
   Stretch provided in: pixels

   Resize down: VERY smooth. Better than JanFX.SmoothResize.
   Resize up: better (sharper) than JanFX.SmoothResize
   Time: similar to JanFx

   BitBlt only does copy. NO STRETCH

   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162950(v=vs.85).aspx
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
function StretchF(BMP: TBitmap; OutWidth, OutHeight: Integer): TBitmap;
begin
 if (BMP.Width < 12) OR (BMP.Height< 12) then
  begin
   ShowMessage('Cannot stretch images under 12 pixels!');   { 'WinStretchBltF' will crash if the image size is too small (below 10 pixels)}
   EXIT(NIL);
  end;

 Result:= TBitmap.Create;
 TRY
  Result.PixelFormat:= BMP.PixelFormat; { Make sure we use the same pixel format as the original image }
  SetLargeSize(Result, OutWidth, OutHeight);
  SetStretchBltMode(Result.Canvas.Handle, HALFTONE);
  SetBrushOrgEx    (Result.Canvas.Handle, 0,0, NIL);
  StretchBlt(Result.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Result.Width, Result.Height, BMP.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, BMP.Width, BMP.Height, SRCCOPY);
 FINALLY
  FreeAndNil(Result);
  RAISE;
 END;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

for any type of images, you can use this:

```
img := TIMage.create(nil);
img.picture.loadfromfile('any_file_type');
Result:= TBitmap.Create;
result.Width := newWidth;
result.Height := newHeight;
Result.Canvas.Draw(0,0,img.Picture.Graphic);
```