# Resize images and save output

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I see many questions/Answers about resizing images here on SO.

But I can't find the correct one that fit my case.

**[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111447/how-to-resize-a-picture)**, it works only when you want to have a small image from a big one.

However if you have a picture with 24x24 dimension and you want to resize it to 256x256 dimension, the `procedure` will fail and gives you a distorted picture.

The code below is my attempt to sort out my issue

```
  Graph := TBitmap.Create;
  try   // After loading a .bmp file to Image1 with 48x48 dimension 
    Graph.Assign( Image1.Picture.Bitmap );
    Graph.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, 255, 255), Graph);
    Graph.SetSize(255,255);
    Graph.SaveToFile('Location\Resault.bmp');
  finally
    Graph.Free;
  end;
```

The original image:

[image]

The result (the white square with the black part on the upper left):

[image]

How can we load an image to a `TImage` and convert/resize it and save changes?

Comment: Use a temp Bitmap with 255x255 and StretchDraw the small one on it. then assign back to `Graph` if you wish. do not expect to see great results when resizing a small image into a big one.

Comment: @kobik Thanks for the comment, I'll give it a try

Comment: or that @Sami http://chrislema.com/how-to-resize-images-to-make-them-larger-without-losing-quality/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to **[kobik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937125/kobik)** for the comment, it was useful.

```
var Graph : TBitmap; Conv : TBitmap;
begin

      Graph := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        Graph.Assign( Image1.Picture.Bitmap );
        Conv := TBitmap.Create;
        try
          Conv.SetSize(255,255);
          Conv.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, 255, 255), Graph);
          Conv.SaveToFile('Location\Resault.bmp');   
        finally
          Conv.Free;
        end;

      finally
        Graph.Free;
      end;

end;
```

Comment: In this code, you can remove the Graph variable and directly use Image1.Picture.Bitmap

Comment: You mean 256 when you say 255

Comment: @PatrickPREMARTIN Well, I have done that and It always extended the image with black background. Then, it saved it as it was shown on the TImage. This was the only way I was able to successfully resize and save...

Comment: @ThN Do you use VCL or FMX ?

Comment: StretchDraw will look terrible, I'd use GR32 resamplers.

Comment: Or maybe not, bicubic looks really blurry for this image https://i.imgur.com/1f9ctr8.png